# Trying to create Login to Headless Wordpress through React Web App

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta

I'm kind of new to React. I am currently trying to build a Web App for my Organization's magazines, but the first hurtle we need to jump over is the login verification. Since all of our subscribers are in Wordpress, I need to somehow authenticate their WP Username and Password through the app. Currently I am trying to use Okta and MiniOrange SAML SSO. Does anyone have any experience with this, that would be willing to help me? I would sincerely appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okta and MiniOrange can only authenticate your users if they have credentials for them, usually from an enterprise store such as LDAP or an AD domain so the straight answer is you really can't get there from here.

Those services will allow you to login to Wordpress using SAML or OIDC, but not allow you to login to your custom application using credentials stored in Wordpress.

There may be Wordpress plugins or APIs that will allow a user to authenticate using WP credentials though. That would be my starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it's been a rough experience so far

Comment: If you remove the SAML SSO from the picture, your best bet is going to be here: https://github.com/mattberg/wp-json-api-auth or here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-auth/